# Unexpected token, expected ")" inside axios try-catch statement

Tags: reactjs, typescript, try-catch, react-typescript

I'm getting a strange issue `Unexpected token, expected ")"`  when trying to add the type as `any` of the exception `e` in the try-catch statement. Its working fine when `any` type is removed from the catch block. (Adding `any` explicitly as without it git pipeline fails)

```
 try {
      await axios.patch(
        "/scriptschedule/" + pk + "/",
        postData
      );
      setSubmitting(false);
      afterCreateOrUpdateAction();
    } catch (e: any) {
      setSubmitting(false);
      let message =
        e.response.data && e.response.data.non_field_errors
          ? e.response.data.non_field_errors
          : "Error. Please try again";
      addToast({
        id: "1",
        title: "Error",
        color: "danger",
        text: <p>{message}</p>,
      });
    }
```

[image]

The syntax looks fine to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: Does something like `catch ((e: any)) {` fix it at all?

Comment: @Ashley No. It throws up a parsing error.

Comment: Ah, looking at [this PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9999) seems to show it isn't possible to annotate the error in the catch clause. What specific error is your git pipeline throwing?

Comment: @Ashley Thank you very much for sharing the reference. git pipeline gave the error `Object is of type unknown.  TS2571` on destructuring `e.response.data`. . Temporarily solved it by giving `(e as any).response.data`

Comment: I would say perhaps start considering that temporary solution permanent. I reckon that's the way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to put a type annotation on the error in the `catch` clause. The solution to this would be to cast the variable (as I believe you've done).

```js
try { 
  // ...
} catch (e) {
  (e as any)...
}
```